# Why is an interpreter slower than a compiler in practice?

Tags: compiler-construction, interpreter

Don't they both have to convert to machine code at some point to execute or am i missing something more basic?

**EDIT:**

*Please consider more sophisticated interpreting schemes e.g. cases where the code is translated to Byte code and the byte code is only regenerated when source code changes e.g. CPython implementation of Python?
I am not really interested in ancient interpreters that re-execute line by line....*

Thanks!

Comment: A pure interpreter does not convert to machine code. It may process directly ASTs or convert to virtual machine code (bytecode) and process that.

Comment: yeah there is an intermediate step...but when you say "process that"...what does that mean? does it not have to turn into machine code before it is executed? if not is that why it is slower?

Comment: @algorithmicCoder, consider a typical stack VM bytecode interpretation: for a sequence `PUSH 2; PUSH 2; ADD` it will update stack pointer three times, perform three costly memory read/write operations, while in a native code you'll most likely stick to the registers. The latter can be 100x times faster, even for such a trivial example.

Comment: @algorithmicCoder, see my longer post below.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

A **compiled** language like C is usually compiled directly into **machine code**. When you run the code, it is executed directly by the CPU.

A fully **interpreted** language like BASIC or PHP is usually interpreted each time it runs. When you execute your code, the CPU executes the interpreter, and the interpreter reads and executes your source code. (PHP can be classified as fully interpreted, since while it does use opcodes, they are usually thrown away after the execution.)

A **bytecode interpreted** language like Python, is compiled from source code to **bytecode** that is executed by a virtual machine. The CPU runs the VM, and the VM executes each bytecode instruction. In Python, the bytecode is compiled the first time code is executed.

In Java, bytecode is compiled ahead of execution. The Java VM also has a special feature called **Just-in-time compilation**. This means that during execution, it may compile some of the *bytecode* to *machine code*, which it can send to the CPU to execute directly.

In conclusion, with compiled languages, the CPU runs the code directly. In interpreted languages, the CPU usually runs the interpreter or virtual machine. This makes interpreted languages generally slower than compiled languages, due to the overhead of running the VM or interpreter.

NOTE: While we speak of interpreted and compiled *languages*, what we are really discussing is the usual execution style of a language. PHP can be compiled (using HipHop), and C can be interpreted (using Parrot VM).

Comment: +1 for 'While we speak of interpreted and compiled languages, what we are really discussing is the usual execution style of a language.'

Answer (score 7):

OK, a lot of incorrect posts here, time for a long answer.

A compiler is basically clear - it translates a program form the source language to the target language. Both languages can be whatever - high level language, virtual machine bytecode, machine code.

An interpreter, on the other hand does not perform a *translation*, but *directly performs* the actions, prescribed by the source language construct, a.k.a. interprets it.

Let's consider a hypothetical `add` instruction in a stack based machine, which adds the two top elements of the stack and pushes the result back. An interpreter will *directly perform* that "add the two top elements and push the result back", in a manner similar to:

```
switch (op)
{

 ....

  case OP_ADD:  
    op1 = pop (stack);
    op2 = pop (stack);
    res = op1 + op2;
    push (stack, res);
    break;

...
}
```

As you can see, for a single `add` insn, there are many operations performed: reading and writing memory, incrementing and decrementing the stack pointer, the add operation itself, the overhead of the switch (if the interpreter is implemented that way), the overhead of the loop which reads each subsequent insn and decides how to process it, etc.

If the interpeter worked on an AST, it may look like:

```
swicth (op)
{
   ...
   case OP_ADD:
     op1 = tree->eval (left);
     op2 = tree->eval (right);
     return op1 + op2;
   ...
}
```

Again, many, many insns to perform whatever is required by the `add` semantics.

Comment: True. But, a modern VM implementation won't be that simple: it can be either a direct threaded code (see the OCaml bytecode VM for example), or all the instructions can be inlined. But still, most of the implementations won't bother translating a stack semantics into 3-address.

Comment: @SK-logic, yes, a modern VM implementation would be a hybrid compiler/interpreter and the interpreter part would be written in either assembler or C with extensions (like computed goto), if it exists at all. Speaking of implementation techniques, I've seen some interpreter, which actually kept the top three or so elements of the operand stack in registers.

Comment: Modern VMs also do JIT compiling which takes a slight performance hit when compiling but after that runs at the speed of native code (depending on how well the JIT can optimize, of course)

Answer (score 3):

A compiler translates a program to machine code before you run the program. It resolves all variables, types at compile time.

An interpreter typically translates each statement to machine code each time the statement is executed.

Comment: How about cases where the code is translated to Byte code and the byte code is only regenerated when source code changes e.g. CPython implementation of Python?

Comment: It is not nearly a "*typical*" way of interpretation. Virtual machines are a much more typical implementation in 21st century. Ruby, Perl, Python, Lua, whatever else - everything is VM-compiled now.

Comment: yes this is the real source of my confusion...why exactly is Python then said to be slower than say C++ or Java even though  it is actually compiled into bytecode...i am guessing the execution of the program after it is turned into bytecode is the tricky part...why is this part slower than when we just compile and run?

Comment: @algorithmicCoder, Python execution is slower mainly because of its dynamic type system, which makes it virtually impossible to compile it efficiently to a native code. It is the very semantics of the language which makes it "slow", not the interpretation.

Comment: Aha! this is what i suspected. Ok now can you explain briefly HOW the type system comes into play. Do types have to be figured out EVERY time the interpreter runs the byte code? What does this entail? Or is it figure out only when the source code is compiled to byte code?.... sorry if these are basic questions...also i'd appreciate a good book to use in learning these fundamentals!

Comment: @algorithmicCoder, every time Python is executing, say, `a+b`, it have to get the type of `a`, type of `b` and dispatch the appropriate addition implementation (concatenation for strings, integer addition for integers, etc.). It does not matter if you compile it to native or to a bytecode, the bottleneck will always be in this dynamic dispatch. Of course there are some funny tricks for getting rid of the dynamic typing - e.g., V8 and the other modern Javascript compilers are using a form of an abstract interpretation for specialising types where possible.

Comment: @SK-logic Very late to the party, but how come semantically similar languages like Julia be this much faster if the main factor are said semantics?

Comment: @Raumschifffan Julia is only fast when type annotations are used (or when types can be inferred). Otherwise it is too resorting to dynamic dispatch, with a significant performance hit. Same goes for Common Lisp, Scheme and other dynamically typed languages - and most of their implementations are of much higher quality than Python, yet they take a noticable performance hit every time dynamic dispatch is involved.

Answer (score 3):

A borderline between compilation and interpretation is blurred. In general, *some*  forms of interpretation are working slower than a directly compiled code. It may not necessarily be true in specific cases.

For example, some interpreters are directly executing virtual machine instructions (sometimes translated into a direct or indirect threaded code), which is slower than a native code for obvious reasons.

Since there is an impedance mismatch between semantics of the VM (e.g., most of them are stack-based) and semantics of the native code, any ad hoc translation from one to another will be sub-optimal. In order to perform heavyweight optimisations you'll need a virtual machine (or any other form of an intermediate representation) with a certain amount of a target platform specific semantics in it. LLVM is a good example of such a representation.

Some other interpreters are even evaluating the code on an abstract syntax tree level. Some are performing string substitution (a notorious example is Tcl).

All that techniques are easy to implement, they provide some interesting dynamic properties to the language semantics, but all at a cost of a slower execution.

Another important thing to mention is a [supercompilation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metacompilation). This technique practically turns any interpreter into a compiler, by specialising the interpreter implementation against a specific instance of a code to be executed. Existence of such approaches renders a difference between compilation and interpretation even more vague.

Answer (score 2):

As per [WikiPedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_%28computing%29):

> Interpreting code is slower than running the compiled code because the interpreter must analyze each statement in the program each time it is executed and then perform the desired action, whereas the compiled code just performs the action within a fixed context determined by the compilation. This run-time analysis is known as "interpretive overhead". Access to variables is also slower in an interpreter because the mapping of identifiers to storage locations must be done repeatedly at run-time rather than at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler does it once (which takes some time), then the code runs fast.
As it can take quite a while, it can spend quite some time optimizing the code too.

The interpreter does it when you want to run the code, so it compiles each time you run it.

Answer (score -1):

Interpreter executes line by line and converts each line to machine instruction at **run time**. Whereas compiler converted entire program from source language to target language ( most probably machine instruction of the target processor ) in the **compile time**.

Comment: This answer is not correct. Interpreter may not executes line by line and converts each line to machine instruction at run time.